# Find resistors for an OP AMP

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, resistors, circuit-analysis, design

[image]

Somebody could help me to understand the first question? I am struggling to build the equation to solve it

Comment: It's an interesting circuit and a good exercise. First find an expression for the voltage at the T junction, bearing in mind what you know about the voltages at the opamp inputs.

Comment: Prove that this circuit can be used as an inverting amplifier by finding vo/vi gain equation.

Comment: The voltage at the inverting input is (near enough) zero. The current through R1 must be balanced by the current through the  R3 connected to that input. The output voltage (Vo) is divided by R3 and R2. (remember that there is another R3 in parallel with R2). The overall gain is -400 (Vo/Vin). You have everything you need to work it out.

Comment: Vin * ((R2 || R3) +R3) = - V0 * R1 
Would be a good equation to start off?

Comment: Note that you have three unknowns (resistor values) in the given circuit, while you are given only one constraint -- the required gain. This means that you are expected to understand secondary issues, such as the ramifications of using very small or very large resistance values in certain locations.

Comment: Problems:  The opamp is shown as a single-supply opamp with the negative supply terminal  and the non-inverting input grounded and with Vin positive. Since the circuit is to have a gain of -400, and since the input voltage is shown as positive, the best the output can do is hug the positive rail, so there's a problem.  If the input is allowed to go negative, or if the opamp supply can be bipolar, then the problem goes away and there are many solutions to the problem.

Comment: I think that this is the point, it has many combinations for R1,2,3... but the problem is what assumptions do I have to make to find at least one of them?

Comment: R1 = 1k ohm
R2 = R1
R3 = 399k ohms...

does it sound good?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a homework question with no evidence of an initial attempt by the OP

Comment: it is not a homework, sorry about that... it is a question I saw ... I tried to do many many times, but the theory behind it ...is not clear to me, it is not a homework ... I can assure you that

Answer (score 1):

The problem's circuit won't work as shown, and I missed that the horizontal resistors in the "T" network are supposed to be equal, but if the opamp's supply is allowed to be bipolar, here's one way to get the circuit to work:

1. Select Vout to be a value close to the opamp's negative
   supply,leaving enough headroom so the opamp's output won't be
   clipped, say -20 volts.
2. Since the circuit inverts and its gain is to be -400, Vin must
   be:

$$ Vin =\frac {-(-Vout)}{Av} = \frac {20V}{400} = 0.05V = 50\text { millivolts}$$

3. Since U1's non-inverting input (U1+) is grounded, U1- will be a
   virtual ground, so pick a value for R1 which will drop 50 millivolts
   with a decent amount of current through it, say 5 microamps. Then:

$$ R1 = \frac{Vin}{Iin} = \frac {50mV}{5\mu A} = 10k \text{ ohms}$$

4. With 5 microamps through R1 and with VIN equal to 50 millivolts,
   you'll need a  current sink which can pull U1- down to zero volts.
   One way to do it is to use another equal valued resistor (R2) which
   will also drop 50 millivolts with the R2 R3 R4 (V4) junction at -50
   millivolts.

   Since R1 and R2 are in series, and the current through R1 is 5
   microamps, the current out of R2 must be -5 microamperes.
5. If the R2 R3 R4 junction is to sit at -50 millivolts, and the
   resistance of R3 is chosen, arbitrarily, to be 10k ohms, then R3
   must drop 50 millivolts and the current out of R3 and into the R2 R3
   R4 junction must be -5 microamps.

   Then, with Vout at -20 volts,

$$ R4 = \frac{Vout-V4}{I3} = \frac {(-20V)-(-50mV)}{10\mu A} = 1,995,000\Omega \approx 2  \text { megohms.} $$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

T feedback is to reduce the size of the feedback resistor in larger gain circuits.  a single large resistor will interact differently with the device capacitances.  You can find out how to analyze here; [enter link description here](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?baseLiteratureNumber=slaa068&fileType=pdf)